# printf(), unsigned char, and %hhd

Tags: c, printf

The program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <limits.h>

int main( void )
{
#ifdef __CHAR_UNSIGNED__
    printf( "%d\n", __CHAR_UNSIGNED__ );
#endif
    printf( "%d\n", CHAR_MAX );
    printf( "%d\n", CHAR_MIN );
    printf( "%hhd\n", CHAR_MAX );
}
```

Output (on my x86_64 desktop):

```
127
-128
127
```

That is as expected. Now, I ran the same on a Raspberry Pi (ARM):

```
1
255
0
-1
```

So... **apparently I have misunderstood** some step `CHAR_MAX` is taking in its way to output, as **the output I was expecting** in that last line -- passing `CHAR_MAX` to `%hhd` on a machine with `char` being unsigned -- **would have been `255`**.

(And if you should ask, the result is the same for `(char)CHAR_MAX`, and `(unsigned char)CHAR_MAX`.)

What am I missing?

This happened to me during regression testing my own `printf()` implementation on the Raspberry Pi -- which, by the way, *does* print `255`. So... only one implementation is doing it right, and I have the sinking feeling it's not mine...

Comment: "Output (on my x86_64 desktop):..." You're missing a line. A very important line.

Comment: Think about what that `__CHAR_UNSIGNED__` being non-zero could mean... And remember that it's implementation specific if `char` is `signed` or `unsigned`.

Comment: What is `__CHAR_UNSIGNED__ ` ???

Comment: @MadPhysicist: Actually I was missing two lines in my program, which I added after the x86_64 compiler barked at me. ;-)

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude: I **am** thinking about what `__CHAR_UNSIGNED__` means. That was why I was expecting the ARM output for `%hhd` to read `255` instead of `-1` for `CHAR_MAX`...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The format `"%hhd"` is for a **signed** byte. If you pass an *unsigned* byte then you technically have *undefined behavior*. To print an *unsigned* byte you need to use `"%hhu"`.

What really happens is because of how [two's complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two's_complement) integers work, and that `0xff` is equal to `-1`.

Comment: head -> desk. Of course. {Cursing voice fading into the background...}

Comment: So now I may debug my `printf()` to figure out what went wrong - wrong in there. :-D Geeeeeez....

Comment: Hmmm... on second thought... if passing an unsigned value to `%hhd` is UB, does it really matter that my implementation gives a different result...? (Just talking to myself here, feel free to not answer. ;-) )

Comment: @DevSolar is your implementation give `0` for `printf( "%hhu\n", 256);` ? I suspect not ;)

Comment: @Stargateur: It does, actually. ;-)

Comment: @Stargateur: I am curious, though... why did you ask?